# Remove openjdk from Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Why if i want remove openjdk, apt-get installs new packages.

```
sudo apt-get purge openjdk-6-jre
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  gcj-4.6-base gcj-4.6-jre gcj-4.6-jre-headless gcj-4.6-jre-lib gcj-jre gcj-jre-headless icedtea-7-jre-jamvm libbonobo2-0 libbonobo2-common libgcj-common
  libgcj12 libgcj12-awt libgnome2-0 libgnome2-bin libgnome2-common libidl-common libidl0 liborbit2 openjdk-7-jre openjdk-7-jre-headless openjdk-7-jre-lib
Suggested packages:
  fastjar gcj-4.6-jdk gcj-jdk libbonobo2-bin libgcj12-dbg desktop-base icedtea-7-plugin sun-java6-fonts fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-ipafont-mincho
  ttf-telugu-fonts ttf-oriya-fonts ttf-kannada-fonts ttf-bengali-fonts
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  default-jre* icedtea-netx* openjdk-6-jre*
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gcj-4.6-base gcj-4.6-jre gcj-4.6-jre-headless gcj-4.6-jre-lib gcj-jre gcj-jre-headless icedtea-7-jre-jamvm libbonobo2-0 libbonobo2-common libgcj-common
  libgcj12 libgcj12-awt libgnome2-0 libgnome2-bin libgnome2-common libidl-common libidl0 liborbit2 openjdk-7-jre openjdk-7-jre-headless openjdk-7-jre-lib
0 upgraded, 21 newly installed, 3 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 49.7 MB/66.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 119 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

Why "21 newly installed"???. I simply want deinstall openjdk and not install new packages. Maybe it is because that i installed libreoffice.
PS.

Comment: Same thing is happening to me.  It seems that Ubuntu is forcing you to have one of openjdk of gcj installed.  I want to uninstall both!